# Install Gitlab in other directory Centos7

Tags: installation, gitlab, centos

I would like to install Girlab in my centos7.9.

I would like to know how can I install packages in other directory. I have a directory called /appli and I would like to do the install on this directory.

Does somebody has a idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it could be done if you were to build it from the source. I've never tried to do that. I remember that I came across a discussion on this topic at the [GitLab forum](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/is-there-a-way-to-install-gitlab-to-different-directory/57046/3).